# Regex or Match String with only one piece that dynamically changes

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match a directory like string, that contains a number that can change.

Example: `/MonkeyText/mserver0/`

The string can also have more to it after the trailing slash example:
`/MonkeyText/mserver0/hello/some/thing/yes.ext` or `/MonkeyText/mserver0/hello/some/thing/`

however what I am trying to figure out is what is the best way to see if the string in question is just `/MonkeyText/mserver0/` and nothing else, aside from the number that can be anything from 0 to 100000 and up. I'm not 100% how I should approach this, that doesn't involve splitting the string and trying to count how many values are in it after the split then trying to figure out if the last digit(s) are numeric. That way sounds like it may be more than is needed.

Comment: you mean this `^\/MonkeyText\/mserver\d+\/$` ?

Comment: would I use something like that with `.match()` ?

Comment: You can use: `var valid = /^\/MonkeyText\/mserver\d+\/$/.test(input);`

Answer (score 0):

Use start and end patterns in does an exact match.

```
> var str = "/MonkeyText/mserver0/foo";
undefined
> var result = str.match(/^\/MonkeyText\/mserver\d+\/$/g)
undefined
> result
null
> var str = "/MonkeyText/mserver0/";
undefined
> var result = str.match(/^\/MonkeyText\/mserver\d+\/$/g)
undefined
> result
[ '/MonkeyText/mserver0/' ]
```

OR

```
> var valid = /^\/MonkeyText\/mserver\d+\/$/.test("/MonkeyText/mserver0/");
undefined
> valid
true
> var valid = /^\/MonkeyText\/mserver\d+\/$/.test("/MonkeyText/mserver0/foo");
undefined
> valid
false
```